# Proof of Differentiate under the integral

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

there are four conditions but I want to know where condition **$(i)$** is uesd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first condition is used in the first line.

$$u(y+h) - u(y) = \int_S f(y+h,s) - f(y,s)\,\mu(ds)$$

would not necessarily make sense if we didn't know that

$$\int_S \lvert f(x,s)\rvert \, \mu(ds) < \infty$$

for all $x \in (y-\delta,y+\delta)$.